# Translate simple code snippet - Get taxonomy term id

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

im following [this great podcast](http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode31) which is drupal 5 (i guess).

I want to add a View into my page--taxonomy.tpl.php and get the id of the taxonomy term im currently looking at. Could maybe anybody translate this code snippet for drupal 7?

```
<?php
$view = views_get_view('taxonomypages');
$display = $view->execute_display('block_1', 2);
print $display['content'];
?>
```

I figured out that this shows me the view:

```
$view = views_get_view('taxonomypages');
print $view->preview('block_1',$tids);
```

but $tids is undefined.
i need to have the current taxonomy term id that im looking at e.g when im at `taxonomy/term/12` the id is 12 but $tids is undefined.

Comment: Are you trying to show a custom view instead of the standard taxonomy term page? If so, just enable the "Taxonomy term" view that is disabled by default and modify it to your liking.

Comment: What MotoTribe said sounds like the "Drupal Way". You can then use arguments from the url to get the id of the taxonomy term

Answer (score 1):

I never used "page--taxonomy.tpl.php", but based upon what you want to do, I guess your looking for taxonomy-term.tpl.php.

In Drupal 7, you have a $term variable, from which you can get the tid. Below is some D7 code I've used for a similar purpose, that I adapted a bit to yours. Note that the argument to Views *must* be in an array.

```
$view = views_get_view('taxonomypages');
$view->execute_display('panel_pane_1', array($term->tid));
$output = $view->render();
```

But I do *not* recommend you proceed down this path. Instead use [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels), and pass the argument to a View that way. Yes, it will require a bit more configuration, but it will also be much more sustainable, easier to maintain, and keep less logic in the template files.

Relevant panels tutorials [here](http://dev.nodeone.se/en/learn-page-manager).

Comment: thanks for your answer! you missed a $ in the last line. But anyway im getting an error message that $term is undefined "Notice: Undefined variable: term in include() (..." :(

Comment: Thanks, I added the missing $. Which file exactly are you in? I added a note about the D7 file I think you should be using. Again, I would go with Panels instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you already are on the term page it is possible to use the URL argument to determine the term id. The term id should be in `arg(2)`.

```
$tid = arg(2);
```